# Background-image not showing up

Tags: html, css

For some reason, when I attempt to display a cloud image (which I made exactly the same way as the hill image), it doesn't show up! How come? Both images are .png files. However, the tree image has a solid background (not transparent) the clouds have a transparent background. Is this what is causing the issue? If so, how do I fix it?

```
html
{

    /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */ 
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(1, #00A3EF));

    /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */ 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #00A3EF 100%);

}


.sky {
    background: url(clouds2.png) repeat-x; 
    display:     block;
    width:       500px;
    height:      500px;
     border: 1px solid red; 
}







<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3c.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11-strict.dtd">

<!-- START HTML -->
<html>

    <!-- START HEAD -->
    <head>

        <!-- Adding title, meta, link to css and scripts to javascript files -->
        <title>27 Days</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/27.css" />

    <!-- END HEAD -->
    </head>

    <!-- START BODY -->
    <body>

        <!-- Creating div to encompass our entire piano -->
        <div class="sky" id="sky">
            <div class="clouds1" id="clouds1"></div>
            <div class="clouds2" id="clouds2"></div>
        </div>

    <!-- END BODY -->
    </body>

<!-- END HTML -->
</html>
```

Comment: (a) What browser are you testing in? (b) Have you verified that `clouds2.png` is in the same directory as the HTML file (and the background image that *was* working)?

Comment: if this code is in a css stylesheet file, your image clouds2.png must be in the same directory of this file.

Comment: @EmeraldCoder yes it is. as i said, i have another image, that does not have a transparent background (image of hills) and it shows up. but the cloud one - which has a transparent background doesnt... any ideas? thanks for the responses btw

Comment: So if you leave everything else the same and substitute a different image (without a transparent background) in place of `clouds2.png`, it displays correctly?

Comment: @paddy correct. I wish i could post an image to show you guys. not enough points though...

Comment: Well you could always link your image via a free file-sharing site and we could check if there's something fundamentally wrong with it.

Comment: @JonathanNewmuis i'm testing in chrome .. using linux... but this shouldn't matter since the other .png image appears..

Comment: @BlackSky That's not much use...  You uploaded the images to a site that converts the format.  I'm interested in seeing whether there is something about the PNG that your browser can't handle.  This is like providing a compiled executable when asked for source code.

Comment: Can you please also post the html that you use ?

Comment: @paddy can you tell me a site i can post them on?

Comment: Instead of asking someone else, try typing "free file sharing site" into google.  It's very easy.  Here is one result: [100 of the Best Free File Hosting Upload Sites - FileShareFreak](http://filesharefreak.com/2009/08/26/100-of-the-best-free-file-hosting-upload-sites)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, you must specify a colour as the first parameter to `background`, and also put the image in single quotes:

```
background: transparent url('clouds2.png') repeat-x;
```

Comment: hmmm it is still not showing up with these changes. any other ideas?